# Does $(I,c)=R$ hold under given conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra

> For a proper ideal $I$ of $R$ and for any nonunit $c$ outside $I,$ can $(I,c)=R?$ If not does such a result hold when $R$ is a PID?

Please help me.

Comment: If we're talking about commutative rings, then you are just asking about when $I$ and $(c)$ are comaximal. Hagen von Eitzen's solution demonstrates this in the integers.

Answer (score 1):

This can be the case for example if $I$ is maximal.
But you may also consider $R=\mathbb Z$, $I=9\mathbb Z$ and $c=2$, where $I$ is not maximal.